# How to create ExtJs dashboard with fixed and flex width columns?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dashboard

In ExtJs6, we can config the column width with:
 columnWidths:[0.1, 0.7, 0.2],
This will make the columns with 10%,70% and 20% of the dashboard's whole width.

But I want to make the first and third columns have a fixed width, and the middle one always has the left.

Anybody has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [border layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.layout.container.Border.html) instead. The left and right regions (west and east) would be given those fixed widths. The center region is your middle and by default takes all of the remaining width.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ext.layout.container.Column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.layout.container.Column.html) description you can do something like this:

```
// Mix of width and columnWidth -- all columnWidth values must add up
// to 1. The first column will take up exactly 120px, and the last two
// columns will fill the remaining container width.

Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Layout - Mixed',
    layout:'column',
    items: [{
        title: 'Column 1',
        width: 120
    },{
        title: 'Column 2',
        columnWidth: 0.7
    },{
        title: 'Column 3',
        columnWidth: 0.3
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```